# How can I subscribe to a webhook of my companies posts on LinkedIn?

Tags: linkedin-api

I currently have 2 linkedin apps. I did not want two apps, but it looks like the Community Events API requires it be alone on an app. Below is an explanation of the apps:

One app, has the following products activated:

- Share on LinkedIn
- Sign In with LinkedIn
- Advertising API.

It also has Webhooks active. However, what I really want is to get notified when my company posts on linkedin via webhook.

For that, my understanding is that you need to activate the  Community Management API product. However, this product does not allow you to activate any other products, so I needed to create a new app with just the  Community Management API product active.

This has caused me confusion as each app has it's own authentication. The point I'm stuck at is this part of the documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/integrations/community-management/organizations/organization-social-action-notifications?view=li-lms-2023-04&tabs=curl#creating-and-updating-subscriptions

I am missing the webhook tab in the second app with the community management api product. Because of that, I validated my webhook using the first app, but I'm unable to subscribe to events. How can I get the webhook tab on the second app?

I have tried following the examples on the documentation using the data from the community events api app.